# http to https redirecting to the homepage each time

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, concrete5

We have a website, which is divestyle.co.uk and recently we have setup a SSL certificate. This all works great, however we have found an issue. Some of the non https are indexed on Google, instead of just going to the https version of the page they redirect to the homepage.

**For example:**
https://www.divestyle.co.uk/services/ works fine, but if you remove the ’s’ and just put in
http://www.divestyle.co.uk/services/ it takes you to the homepage, with this URL:
https://www.divestyle.co.uk/index.php and adds index.php to the URL which is no good.

We want it to just redirect to the https version of the page instead of going to the index.php each time. The site is built using Concrete5 and also has some rules or the Wordpress blog and the Magento shop that my client has on the same hosting package.

Also, the online shop does not use the SSL, https://www.divestyle.co.uk/dive-shop/. Any ideas why not?

Here is the full htaccess code we are using.

```
# -- concrete5 urls start --

# -- Force www: #
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# -- Wordpress #
RewriteRule ^divestyle_blog/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule divestyle_blog/. divestyle_blog/index.php [L]
# -- /Wordpress #

# --Magento #
RewriteRule ^dive-shop/index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule dive-shop/. dive-shop/index.php [L]

# -- /Magento #
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.html !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}/index.php !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# -- concrete5 urls end --

# force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.divestyle.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: You should do this earlier, not last thing after all the system specific rules have been evaluated. This belongs into the same place where you are already forcing the redirect to the www subdomain.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, works a treat now.

Comment: @ChrisD: With >= c5.7 you could do this in the dashboard under yourdomain.com/dashboard/system/seo/urls -> there you have to set both URLs and also check the tick.